# Testing user-supplied code w/ React/Django

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, eval, user-input

Working on an application that delivers algorithm challenges to users. On the server-side (Django), an Algorithm model has three file fields (one for the markdown description, one for the JavaScript (.js) solution, and one for tests (also .js)).

I'm delivering the content as JSON to a React front-end that's using `react-ace` to collect a user's attempt at solving the challenge.

I'd like to be able to take the submitted code and run my tests against it (using `expect.js`), but having trouble on two fronts:

First, in what environment should I run the user-supplied code on the front-end? I'm assuming no-go on `eval` or `new Function` -- would a Web Worker solve this (I've yet to set one up...)?

Second, how should I integrate the JS tests sent from the server (currently in string form) with the code captured from the user?

Another hiccup: Even when running `eval` I can't get serialized code like below to pick up the `expect` variable that exists on the client-side.

`expect(1).toEqual(1);`

Best case scenario, I'd like to give the user a pre-named function in my Ace Editor which, when submitted, I can run tests on. Any ideas? Thanks!